# what is the difference between Loaded Configuration File displayed in "phpinfo()" and the other diplayed with command "php --ini"

Tags: php, apache, configuration, wamp, httpd.conf

I use wamp server and windows 10 OS,  When i see the phpinfo() information, it shows  Loaded Configuration File  Which is different than Loaded Configuration File displayed when i run php --ini command.

**phpinfo() :**
[image]

**php --ini**
[image]

It's normal to have loaded files are not the same?

And how can i change my Loaded Configuration File?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php --ini is the cli version of php.ini

phpinfo is the php.ini from the webserver

there is a reason that these are separated. Most of the times you want more privileges on one or the other.

to change the version, left click (1 time) system tray wamp icon > php >version 
And select your wanted version. It might give errors but if you really need you might copy one php.ini to the other, but i really advice against this.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have changed the version to 7.3.5 as the way you said, but php --ini still load :  
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.18\php.ini

Comment: It is hidden good, right click the system tray icon>tools>change php cli version>version
Hope this solves your problem. If you are running an older version you need to change the variable in the %PATHS%. forgive me if i dont get the names 100% correct im translating them: control panel > system > advanced system settings > environment variables

Comment: yeeeeeeees it works, i changed environement variables then i added the path of the new version. Thank you